# Invertir una cadena de caracteres en C

Tags: array, string

Este código que, dado una cadena de caracteres en C ejemplo: hola debería imprimir aloh, y lo que pasa es que si coloco el imprimir fuera de los for imprime es hhhh y si lo coloco en el primer `for` me imprime es aaaalllloooohhh

¿cómo se podría solucionar este error?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char cad [20];
char auxiliar [20];

int main () {
    int i,j;
    int largo;
    scanf("%s", cad); 
    
    largo = strlen(cad) ;
    
    for (i=largo; i>=0;i--){
        for (j=0; j<largo ;j++) {
            
            auxiliar [j]= cad[i] ;
        }
        printf ( "%s" , auxiliar );
    }
    //printf ( "%s" , auxiliar );
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que se está imprimiendo la cadena completa en cada iteración del for. Por eso obtienes **aaaalllloooohhhh**.

Si agregas un final de línea al `printf` será más evidente:

```
printf("%s\n" , auxiliar);
```

Si no quieres que eso suceda deberías imprimir solo el resultado final (con el print fuera del for).

En cuanto al otro resultado que obtienes, **hhhh**, se debe a que se repite el mismo caracter en toda la extensión de la cadena. Nota que en el siguiente fragmento, **j** varía de ciclo a ciclo e **i** se mantiene constante:

```
for (j=0; j<largo ;j++) {       
     auxiliar [j]= cad[i];
}
```

---

Por regla general haz tu código lo más simple posible.

En este caso no es necesario emplear 2 for para lo que quieres hacer. Simplemente copia los caracteres de una posición en una cadena a su posición correspondiente en otra cadena.

En este caso necesitarás de un pequeño cálculo para saberlo.

```
for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){
    int j = largo - i - 1;
    auxiliar[i] = cad[j];
}

auxiliar[largo] = 0;
```

Un último paso importante es agregar un carácter nulo luego del último caracter ya que esa es la manera en que las funciones como `strlen` encuentran el final de una cadena. Eso es lo que hace la última instrucción.

Answer (score 2):

También puedes usar`strrev(cad)` que te devuelve la cadena alreves.

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo lo más posible el código original, el programa corregido quedaría así

```
for (i=0; i<largo;i++){
        auxiliar [i]= cad[largo - i - 1];
    }
    auxiliar[largo] = 0;
    printf ("%s", auxiliar);
```